# springdoc-openapi-ui not compatible with openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc-openapi-ui

I started out with an openapi specification (3.0.1) design and generated the code with the openapi-generator-maven-plugin (5.1.0) then I used the springdoc-openapi-ui for spring boot (2.5.4).

I needed to manually migrate most of the annotations in the generated code from io.swagger.annotations.* to io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.* as described here https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox

I would like to generate the code without manually migrating and could not find out yet which generator to use that would be compatible with springdoc-openapi-ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V3 annotations are not supported at this moment. You could do this by overriding mustache templates.

Or just wait 5.3.1 release with the following changes:

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/9775